# Splitting a string before math

Tags: php

If I were to have a string like the following:

```
$string = 1x2,3x5,6x6,;
```

Each section contains for example:

> 1 = amount, x2 = quantity.

Is there a way to split each segment between the commas up, then take the amount and times it by the quantity?

Thank you

Comment: `explode()` once with the comma as the delimiter, `explode()` again on the 'x', convert to int and do your math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - by using [`explode`](http://www.php.net/explode) and [`list`](http://www.php.net/list) (you can do it without `list`, but it makes it easier with it):

```
$string = "1x2,3x5,6x6";
$total = 0;
$explode = explode(",", $string);
foreach ($explode as $explodeSegment) {
    if (trim($explodeSegment) != "") {
        list($amount, $quantity) = explode("x", $explodeSegment);
        $total += ((int)$amount * (int)$quantity);
    }
}
var_dump($total); //int(53)
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/wWBp04hm)

Comment: I am just playing with the code now, and I am getting:  Undefined offset: 1 on list($amount, $quantity) = explode("x", $explodeSegment); Could you explain what might be the reason?

Comment: @ccdavies It seems that it can't find a quantity. What does your `$string` look like?

Comment: Hmm, my string is exactly this: 4x1,1x2,1x1,

Comment: @ccdavies You've got an additional `,` at the end of your string. Either remove it, use `$string = trim($string, ",")` or check out the change in my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function like this.

```
function evaluateExpressions($strings){
    $expressions = explode(",", $strings);
    $expressions = array_filter($expressions);
    $matches = array();
    $results = array();
    foreach($expressions as $expression){
          if (preg_match_all("/([0-9]+)([^0-9])([0-9]+)/", $expression, $matches)){
            array_shift($matches);
            print_r($matches);
            $lh = array_shift($matches)[0];
            $op = array_shift($matches)[0];
            $rh = array_shift($matches)[0];

            switch($op){
                case "x":
                    $results[] = $lh * $rh;
                    break;
                case "+":
                    $results[] = $lh + $rh;
                    break;
                case "-":
                    $retults[] = $lh + $rh;
                    break;
                case "/":
                    $results[] = $lh + $rh;
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new Exception("I don't understand how to use ".$op);
            }


          } else {
            throw new Exception("Malformed Expression List");
          }
    }
    return $results;
}
```

If will evaluate a list of 2 term mathematical expressions and return an array of the results

Example Use:

```
$strings = "1x2,3x5,6x6,";
$dat = evaluateExpressions($strings);
print_r($dat);
```

would yield

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 15
    [2] => 36
)
```

As a bonus it also know how to use the other simple mathematical  operators (+ - x /)