# Exploding an array

Tags: php

If I have the string:

> 123+0,456+1,789+2,

I understand I can do the following:

```
$test = 123+0,456+1,789+2,;
$test = explode(",", $test);
```

This creates an array of each section between ','.

How can I then explode the '+' in each part of the area? and how do I access it?

I know this is probably a very simple question, but everything I have tried has failed.

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Splitting a string before math](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16794313/splitting-a-string-before-math)

Answer (score 3):

Why not use explode again? This time with "+" instead of "," as the delimeter:

```
$test = 123+0,456+1,789+2,;
$test = explode(",", $test);

foreach($test as $test_element){
    $explodedAgain = explode("+", $test_element);
    var_dump($explodedAgain);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$test = "123+0,456+1,789+2,";
$test2 = explode(",", $test);
foreach($test2 as &$v) {
    $v=explode("+", $v);
}
```

this crates a multidimentional array, you can access it this way:

```
$test2[1][0]; // =456
```

Answer (score 0):

When exploding a string, you get returned an array. In your case `$test` is an array. So you'll need to loop through that array to access each part.

```
foreach($test as $subtest){

}
```

In the above loop each part is now listed as `$subtest`. You can then explode `$subtest` using  `explode` again to split the string by '+', this'll return an array again with the bits. You can then work with the bits.

A full example would be:

```
$test = 123+0,456+1,789+2,;
$test = explode(",", $test);

foreach($test as $subtest){
    $bits= explode("+", $subtest);
    print_r($bits);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your code:

```
$newArr = array();
foreach($test as $v)
{
    $newArr[] = explode('+', $v);
}
```

`$newArr` is now an array of arrays containing your numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all('/((\d+)\+(\d)),+/', $test, $matches);
var_export($matches);

array (
    0 =>
    array (
        0 => '123+0,',
        1 => '456+1,',
        2 => '789+2,',
    ),
    1 =>
    array (
        0 => '123+0',
        1 => '456+1',
        2 => '789+2',
    ),
    2 =>
    array (
        0 => '123',
        1 => '456',
        2 => '789',
    ),
    3 =>
    array (
        0 => '0',
        1 => '1',
        2 => '2',
    ),
)
```

primary parts are in $matches[1] (splits by ",") - for result under key 1 secondary splits are in $matches[2][1] and $matches[3][1]